# ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to "Development" somehow limits API calls

Tags: .net, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on a simple .net core API and noticed a strange behavior I can't explain:

API works fine until a point (40-50 calls) where every calls fail and return a HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway after timeout.

After some investigations I figured out this behavior not appearing when I remove the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT (set to development) in config files.

So, concretely, which differences implies my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT setted to Development? How can I manage to get it work with this setting?

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var dbString = Configuration["Database:ConnectionString"];

        services.AddScoped<ISearchEngineRepository, SearchEngineRepository>();
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddDbContext<VvpDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);
        services.AddCors();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseCors(options => options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200").AllowAnyMethod());
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's just an environment variable. The value alone doesn't do anything. As to what effect a different value might have on your application, that is impossible to say without seeing you app code, specifically your `Startup.cs`, though even that may not be enough. All kinds of things can be made to be dependent on a particular environment value, but nothing necessarily by default.

Comment: I see. As far as I remember I don't specify any settings based on this variable (except the env.IsDevelopment() condition in startup.cs I edited on my post above, still same if I remove it tho...). I think that's maybe due to IIS but I have no idea if and how this variable is used there...

Comment: It's not. The `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variable is specifically used by the `IHostingEnvironment` abstraction and as such is always utilized at a programmatic level, i.e. some sort of conditional in your actual code. IIS doesn't know or care about any of this.

Comment: My attention is now focused on the IISSupport folder in the bin folder of the API. There's a file `IISExeLauncherArgs.txt` in it in which `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is mentioned. After deleting bin and obj folder and regenerating the solution, it seems to work fine... But still can't explain why.